# UML 2 JMS Component Representation

Tags: architecture, uml

I'm working on a application that uses several jms resources like Queues and Topics, and i'm currently doing the UML of the design, and i'm not sure about the best way of represent the relation between a publisher and consumer/subscriber in a component diagram when JMS technologies are involved, looking over the internet i found some examples but they are quite different, some represent the queues or topcis as individual components others just as interfaces.

So my doubt is, ¿Which is the correct way in UML 2.0 of represent the use of a JMS Resource like a queue or a topic from both perspectives, publisher and consumer/subscriber?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have already seen, there is not the one solution. I prefer an UML modeling style that focuses on the aspects of your application. Thus a possibility is to model your application using ports to model connections between components (or possibly also between classes - where it is relevant only). Then refine the ports later with the actually used message queues and omit direct dependencies to the JMS classes. This kind of port refinements is more common in SysML modelling but very handy for such stuff and is also possible in UML.

Further, model a package dependency from your application packages to the library, but dependencies from your implementation classes to JMS can be omit. If you want to model all dependencies it would be an idea to have different diagrams, one showing mostly your aspects, one showing the dependencies to libraries.